# swift: support iOS8 with POD which is only for iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods

I have app which works from iOS9.

Now, I want to add support for iOS8 but 1 of my PODS works only from iOS9.
I want that this POD will work for iOS9+ but do not work for iOS8 and I can compile the app.But now I can not compite the app if I set iOS8 in Project settings.

The goal is basically do not compile(?) define POD for iOS8 but compile it for iOS9+

How can I solve that?

Comment: Send a request to the developers of the pod to support iOS 8. But, generally, people would not make effort to support iOS 8 from now. Check the share of iOS versions and you cannot find a number of iOS 8 in recent statistics.

Comment: @OOPer yes, they told me that they will not support it

Comment: Your second option, give up using the pod and develop the same functionality by yourself. But I really recommend you this third option: Do not start supporting iOS 8 from now.

Comment: @OOPer yes, i have checked the stats, it;s less than 0.2% in ios8

Comment: It's astonishing you could have found the number. If you are responsible for the decision to start supporting iOS 8, I dare say it is the ridiculous decision. Do you have any reason you need to support iOS 8?

Comment: @OOPer the reason was to get more downloads. As all I need to do it's a change number in Xcode* Issue was only in 1 POD library

Comment: Read my previous comment. Do your best.